# Updating glibc to 2.21 on CentOS

Tags: centos, glibc

I need to install MySQL 5.6 on a CentOS box. I found what seemed to be a [simple tutorial](http://dbahire.com/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-on-centos-7/), but the first command (`sudo yum install my-sql-community-server`) resulted in this group of errors:

[image]

I ran `yum list glibc` to see what version my box has, and it came up with glibc.x86_64 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7. I tried running `yum -y update glibc`, and it ran with no errors, but when I check the version again, it's still on the same one. How do I update my system to have the libraries that mysql requires?

Comment: Those instructions are for CentOS 7, you appear to be running Centos 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial is specific to RHEL 7 / CentOS 7. It will not work for CentOS 6, precisely because the OS packages in CentOS 6 are older than what you need for the MySQL packages for CentOS 7. You'll need to find a tutorial or instructions for installing on CentOS 6; there are lots of them out there. You'll first need to uninstall the repository package you installed as part of this tutorial, then you can start at the MySQL repository page, http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/.

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar enough with Ubuntu, but not at all with CentOS, so I didn't know what version was running.

Comment: To find the version, look at `/etc/centos-release` - `/etc/redhat-release` on RHEL. Most of your package files will tell you as well - the "el6" in the filename means it's for CentOS 6.